# Odd results when using RPi.GPIO's event_detected() function

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, python-3, robotics

I've recently been experimenting with RPi.GPIO's event_detected() function, to check if a button (connected to the gpio) has been presssed. However, for some reason events would randomly be detected. My program looked a bit like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(36, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=200)

on = False

def main():
        #do things which take about 10 seconds

while True:
        if GPIO.input(35) == 1:
                on = True
        if GPIO.event_detected(36) == 1:
                on = False
        if on == True:
                main()
```

Essentially, the program checks if a button (connected to pin 35) is pressed, if so it sets on to True. on will stay True as long as the button connected to pin 36 isn't pressed. If pin 36's button is pressed then on goes back to False. If on is True the program runs.

However, this wasn't working. Therefore I added `print('pressed')` after `on = False` (3rd to last line). For some reason **even** when the pin 36 button wasn't connected to 3v3 power the presses were still registering, and many false presses were registering. (The pin 35 button, on the other hand works perfectly).

Why does the pin 36 button register a press even when not connected to 3v3 power, and why are there false presses?

Answer (score 0):

If a GPIO set as an INPUT is not connected to a fixed voltage it is said to be floating and will randomly return 0 or 1 when tested.

In your case this shouldn't happen as it is connected to ground via the weak internal pull-down (pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN).  The internal pulls are about 50K.

That suggests there is a wire attached to that GPIO which is acting like an aerial and is randomly getting a signal stronger than the weak internal pull.

A solution is to use a stronger external pull-down, perhaps a 5k resistor between pin 36 and ground.